# Using non standard characters in JavaScript file causing error in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding

In a JavaScript file, I am replacing english words with Turkish ones. Plugin works well in Chrome, firefox but it give exceptional error in IE. Characters causing error is "ö,ü".

What is effective way to solve this problem ?

```
$.fn.raty.defaults = {
    hintList:       ['bad', 'poor', 'regular', 'good', 'gorgeous']
};
```

For example, I replace 'poor' word with 'kötü' and IE says that "you have to specify ']' character".

I understand ö and ü characters damaging structure of JavaScript code flow.

Comment: Please show some code. A question like this can never be answered without seeing actual code.

Comment: Not enough info. What is the error? Where in the script are the characters? (are they inside strings, or part of variable names? ....?

Answer (score 2):

Replace them to Unicode entities (ü = `\u00FC`, ö = `\u00F6`):

```
$.fn.raty.defaults = {
    hintList: ['bad', 'p\u00F6\u00F6r', 'reg\u00FClar', 'g\u00F6\u00F6d', 'g\u00F6rge\u00F6\u00FCs']
    // Will produce ['bad', 'pöör', 'regülar', 'gööd', 'görgeöüs']
};
```

Sorry for my bad Turkish :)